# Which are the causes to get END_TAG error?

Tags: android, ksoap2

At the moment Ican not resolve the question asked in :;

[android: why Am I getting END_TAG error when I execute a function while it is a copy-paste of other which is working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984275/android-why-am-i-getting-end-tag-error-when-i-execute-a-function-while-it-is-a)

My stack error is:

```
09-22 22:43:30.711: W/System.err(3338): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: END_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Body (position:END_TAG </{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}s:Fault>@1:802 in java.io.InputStreamReader@536f30c4) 
09-22 22:43:30.711: W/System.err(3338):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.require(KXmlParser.java:2046)
09-22 22:43:30.715: W/System.err(3338):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:138)
09-22 22:43:30.715: W/System.err(3338):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
09-22 22:43:30.715: W/System.err(3338):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
09-22 22:43:30.715: W/System.err(3338):     at org.tempuri.IAndroid.userPasswordExists(IAndroid.java:304)
09-22 22:43:30.715: W/System.err(3338):     at org.tempuri.IAndroid.getAllProductsAndOffers(IAndroid.java:50)
09-22 22:43:30.715: W/System.err(3338):     at info.android.AllFragment.onCreateView(AllFragment.java:48)
09-22 22:43:30.719: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
09-22 22:43:30.719: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
09-22 22:43:30.719: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
09-22 22:43:30.719: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
09-22 22:43:30.719: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5017)
09-22 22:43:30.723: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
09-22 22:43:30.723: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-22 22:43:30.723: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-22 22:43:30.723: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-22 22:43:30.723: W/System.err(3338):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 22:43:30.727: W/System.err(3338):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 22:43:30.727: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-22 22:43:30.727: W/System.err(3338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 22:43:30.727: W/System.err(3338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 22:43:30.727: W/System.err(3338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-22 22:43:30.727: W/System.err(3338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-22 22:43:30.727: W/System.err(3338):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 22:43:30.727: W/System.err(3338): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 22:43:30.731: W/System.err(3338):     at org.tempuri.IAndroid.getAllProductsAndOffers(IAndroid.java:50)
09-22 22:43:30.731: W/System.err(3338):     at info.android.AllFragment.onCreateView(AllFragment.java:48)
09-22 22:43:30.731: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
09-22 22:43:30.735: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
09-22 22:43:30.735: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
09-22 22:43:30.735: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
09-22 22:43:30.735: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5017)
09-22 22:43:30.735: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
09-22 22:43:30.735: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-22 22:43:30.735: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-22 22:43:30.735: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-22 22:43:30.739: W/System.err(3338):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 22:43:30.739: W/System.err(3338):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 22:43:30.739: W/System.err(3338):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-22 22:43:30.739: W/System.err(3338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 22:43:30.739: W/System.err(3338):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 22:43:30.743: W/System.err(3338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-22 22:43:30.743: W/System.err(3338):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-22 22:43:30.743: W/System.err(3338):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

what are the causes of this error? I want to discard everything you tell me I don't have ideas because I think my code is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until the moment I saw parameters must be the same, and not case sensitive, the same with function name. Could be interestingf to have a list to take care of this. Or maybe a link to read.

Comment: ， what do you mean? David? I get the same error, but I don't know where is the error.